# Is Character.LINE_SEPARATOR in Java unlikely be be found in user input?

Tags: java, unicode, character, constants

I'm implementing a "hack" in a Spring Boot application to implement a 3-part login (company ID, username, password) by mashing up the company ID and username into one text string with a separator, and parsing them out later.  This approach is described [here by Chris Oberle on Baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-extra-login-fields).

Oberle uses `Character.LINE_SEPARATOR` as the separator character.  I'm afraid that could become annoying *if* it's a character someone can easily enter into the login form (for example by hitting Enter or by copy-pasting their username).

My question is: **Is `Character.LINE_SEPARATOR` a good choice of a `Character` constant that's not likely to accidentally find its way into user input?**  And if not, I'm open to suggestions of better choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

[`Character.LINE_SEPARATOR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#LINE_SEPARATOR) is not even a character. It’s a constant corresponding to a *category*, as returned by the `getType` method. In other words, the following code prints `true`:

```
System.out.println(Character.getType('\u2028') == Character.LINE_SEPARATOR);
```

The type of this constant is `byte`, in other words a numerical value, not a character. Therefore, as the linked article contains an expression like

```
String.format("%s%s%s", username.trim(), String.valueOf(Character.LINE_SEPARATOR), domain)
```

which is an unnecessarily expensive way to get the same result as the straight-forward expression

```
username.trim() + Character.LINE_SEPARATOR + domain
```

which will convert the numerical value to its string representation, it is equivalent to the following code:

```
username.trim() + "13" + domain
```

Yes, the [actual value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Character.LINE_SEPARATOR) is `13`, which will get converted to the string `"13"`.

So now, it should become obvious that this is not a good separator, as a legal user name could contain the string `"13"`.

The other question is whether an actual line separator would make a good separator. This depends on whether the value would get transported to the target correctly when containing such a separator. Mind that this has never been tested—the author of the article actually used the string `"13"` as separator.

My suggestion is to just use the `@` sign to separate user name and domain. That’s a well established pattern and no-one would be surprised when you disallow an `@` sign in user and domain names.

Answer (score 1):

Character.LINE_SEPARATOR is a good choice because most inputs should natively not allow them to be entered in, and it is OS agnostic. If you are experiencing problems you can also use another special character like

```
%
```

Then use a ReGeX to ensure they are not allowed to type that in.

But really, Character.LINE_SEPARATOR is your best bet